# DAHDI 3.0.0 not assign spans and cannot generate configuration

Tags: linux, debian, asterisk

I'm setting up a new fresh installation of Debian 10, Asterisk 16 and DAHDI 3.0.0. I have specific the Digium TDM410P 4 port analog card (PSTN) and trying to configure it with asterisk and dahdi. Unfortunately my card is detected from operating system and dahdi_hardware but cannot see it on span-assignments and dahdi_scan, so i can't configure channels and ports!

What wrong with this?

I try it to reinstall dahdi, modules, Asterisk even Debian but I still have not been able to figure out the problem.

```
# lspci
02:06.0 Ethernet controller: Digium, Inc. Wildcard TDM410 4-port analog card (rev 11)
```

```
# lspci -vvv
02:06.0 Ethernet controller: Digium, Inc. Wildcard TDM410 4-port analog card (rev 11)
        Subsystem: Digium, Inc. Wildcard TDM410 4-port analog card
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 64 (16000ns min, 32000ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
        Region 0: I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
        Region 1: Memory at fdbff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at fde00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=100mA  PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
```

```
# dahdi_hardware
pci:0000:02:06.0     wctdm24xxp-  d161:8005 Wildcard TDM410P
```

```
# dahdi_scan
"No output here, nothing"
```

```
# dahdi_genconf -vvvvv
Default parameters from /etc/dahdi/genconf_parameters
Empty configuration -- no spans
Generating /etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf
Empty configuration -- no spans
Generating /etc/dahdi/system.conf
Empty configuration -- no spans
Generating /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

```
# dahdi_cfg -vvvvv
DAHDI Tools Version - 3.1.0-rc1

DAHDI Version: 3.1.0-rc1
Echo Canceller(s):

Configuration
-------------

Channel map:

0 channels to configure.
```

```
# /etc/init.d/dahdi start
Loading DAHDI hardware modules:
   wctdm24xxp: done
/usr/share/dahdi/waitfor_xpds: 106: /usr/share/dahdi/waitfor_xpds: astribank_is_starting: not found
using '/etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf'
Running dahdi_cfg: done.
```

```
# cat /etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf
Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/dahdi_span_assignments on Sun 04 Aug 2019 10:07:50 PM EEST
Map devices + local spans to span + base channel number
```

Comment: Where is your card config? You have configure card, not just put it and hope it is ok. Card config greatly depend of provider on other side of PRI.

Comment: @arheops hello there, no this is not a PRI/BRI (ISDN) card is analog card (PSTN), i think that the dahdi dont load correctly the module because of "wctdm24xxp-" that says on dahdi_hardware. Do you know how i can force it to load it? I run modprobe wctdm24xxp and restart dahdi but no luck

Answer (score 3):

Although the TDM410 and the TDM800 are no longer 'supported' they can be made to work to get yourself out of a mess.

Warning: You're on your own with support.

The example here is using DAHDI 3.1.0 as I found myself in the same mess.
In file `dahdi-linux-complete-3.1.0+3.1.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm24xxp/base.c` add back in the PCI devices for the TDM410 and the TDM800 in my case.

```
static DEFINE_PCI_DEVICE_TABLE(wctdm_pci_tbl) = {
    { 0xd161, 0x2400, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wctdm2400 },
    **{ 0xd161, 0x0800, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wctdm800 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8002, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcaex800 },**
    { 0xd161, 0x8003, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcaex2400 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8005, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wctdm410 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8006, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcaex410 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8007, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcha80000 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8008, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wchb80000 },
    { 0 }
};
```

Comment: Hello there, do you mean that i need to edit this file and add in the configuration??

{ 0xd161, 0x0800, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wctdm800 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8002, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcaex800 }

Comment: For the TDM410P which you have you need to add { 0xd161, 0x8005, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wctdm410 },
    { 0xd161, 0x8006, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, (unsigned long) &wcaex410 },     then run make and make install

Comment: I add the configurations on the file [Configuration Edit](http://prntscr.com/pulvii)
but still no luck. Here is some dahdi commands i execute: [DAHDI Commands](http://prntscr.com/pulvwj). Maybe try other version? [PCI List Details](http://prntscr.com/pulwaa)

Comment: i run the command **modprobe wctdm24xxp** and the card lights turn on and when i runned dahdi_hardware i get ** wctdm24xxp+** but when i run dahdi_genconf its says empty span assignments